# Use Perl to FTP a file behind a HTTP proxy

Tags: perl, proxy, ftp, net-ftp

I have written a simple Perl script to list, get the mtime and then get the files (based on mtime). This has been done using the Perl Net::FTP module that is available in RHEL5/6.

My problem is that I now have to adapt this script to transfer files that are behind a HTTP squid proxy (not a FTP proxy).

I can ftp the files if I use Linux shell commands like wget or lftp after I set up the relevant proxy config files for those programs.

Is there a way to do this in Perl without calling system(shell) commands. I have tried by setting the Net::FTP firewall option (see below) however I believe this is only for FTP proxies which we do not have or use.

My code so far is similar to this (I have left out error handling for clarity):

```
my $host = '111.111.111.111';
my $ftp_port = 21;
my $passive = 0; #Have also tried with passive mode on.
my $firewall = 'proxy.xx:3128';
my $debug = 1;
my $username = 'foo';
my $password = 'bah';

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host, Port=> $ftp_port, Passive => $passive, Firewall => $firewall, Debug => $debug);
$ftp->login($username, $password);
my @file_list = $ftp->ls;
foreach my $file (@file_list) {
    my $mod_time = $ftp->mdtm($file);
    if($mod_time + $wait_time <= time() ) {
        $ftp->get($file);
    }
}
$ftp->quit;
```

Edit: The errors I am receiving are as follows:

```
Net::FTP: new(111.111.111.111, Port => 21, Passive => 0, Firewall => proxy.xx:3128, Debug => 1)
Net::FTP>>> Net::FTP(2.77)
Net::FTP>>>   Exporter(5.63)
Net::FTP>>>   Net::Cmd(2.29)
Net::FTP>>>   IO::Socket::INET(1.31)
Net::FTP>>>     IO::Socket(1.31)
Net::FTP>>>       IO::Handle(1.28)
Net::FTP=GLOB(0x2640e60): Timeout at /etc/transfer/transfer_get.pl line 106
```

I get the same error if I turn passive mode on. If I do not supply the Firewall option I also get a similar timeout error:

```
Net::FTP: new(111.111.111.111, Port => 21, Passive => 1, Debug => 1)
main crashed: Can't ftp to 111.111.111.111: Net::FTP: connect: Connection timed out
```

I'm pretty certain after reading the manual on Net::FTP that it doesn't support transfers through a http proxy on its own. Just wondering what the best method to achieve both listing the mtime of the remote files and then getting them in Perl.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: What happens if you try it behind the proxy? Is there an error message?

Comment: Always provide error messages or nobody can help you.

Comment: Rather than using Net::FTP, you should probably use [LWP](https://metacpan.org/release/libwww-perl).  You can use it to GET a URL that starts 'ftp://' and you can also tell it to use an HTTP proxy.

Comment: Thanks Grant, I will have a look at LWP.

Comment: If you use an ftp: protocol URI, you're still going to need to define an ftp proxy.

Comment: Make sure you can get through to port 20. You might have firewall issues.

Comment: Have you tried setting the http_proxy/ftp_proxy environment variable?